# How to solve ECHO is off. (batch, bat)

Tags: batch-file, echo

I am new to batch. I am trying to echo this to txt, but I am getting: ECHO is off. in cmd.

```
SET /a _rand=(%RANDOM%*5/32768)+1
Set /a zmienna=%zmienna%-%_rand%
set kurczaki=%zmienna%
echo %kurczaki%> bin\DB\smth.txt
```

I tried to change "zmienna" into other variable, but I have still same problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: *N. B.:* There is no need to define a variable (`kurczaki`) to just store the value of another one (`zmienna`). You do not need to enclose variables in `%%` within `set /A`. Then the second line can even be reduced to `set /A zmienna-=_rand`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is probably caused when your result can also be confused as a redirection handle, *i.e. (`1>`, `2>` etc.)*. This can be easily fixed by the way you `echo` it.

You could also simplify your four lines to just two:

```batch-file
Set /A kurczaki=zmienna - ((%RANDOM% %% 5) + 1)
(Echo %kurczaki%) > bin\DB\smth.txt
```

or

```batch-file
Set /A kurczaki=zmienna - ((%RANDOM% %% 5) + 1)
> bin\DB\smth.txt Echo %kurczaki%
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the `ECHO is off/on` message if you just run `echo` with no operands. That means, for some reason, your `kurczaki` variable is not being set to anything. Hence you should echo each variable after you set it to see where the problem lies:

```
SET /a _rand=(%RANDOM%*5/32768)+1
echo .%_rand%.
Set /a zmienna=%zmienna%-%_rand%
echo .%zmienna%.
set kurczaki=%zmienna%
echo .%kurczaki%.
echo %kurczaki%> bin\DB\smth.txt
```

When I do this from the command line, there's a difference when the `>` redirection is hard up against what you're outputting, when that thing can be used as a file handle:

```
C:\Pax> set xx=7
C:\Pax> echo %xx%>zz.txt
ECHO is on.
C:\Pax> type zz.txt
<no output>
C:\Pax> echo %xx% >zz.txt
C:\Pax> type zz.txt
7<space>
```

So I think your solution is just to not do that. What is happening in this case is that the `echo %xx%>zz.txt` is being converted *exactly* into:

```
echo 7>zz.txt
```

which is *not* sending the `7` to the file. Instead, it is attaching file handle `7` to that file and then, because your `echo` is only writing to file handle `1` (standard output), nothing appears in the file.

In addition, because the `%xx%` has been absorbed for the redirection, there are no longer any arguments to echo and you therefore get the `ECHO is off` message. Further proof can be found with:

```
C:\Pax> set xx=1 7
C:\Pax> echo %xx%
1 7
C:\Pax> echo %xx%>zz.txt
1
```

with the `7` being absorbed for the redirection, leaving only the `1`.

But beware that spaces often find their way into output if you don't do it in a certain way. To that end, I would change the line to be:

```
echo>bin\DB\smth.txt %kurczaki%
```

This should both ensure no spaces surrounding the variable in the output file, and also the actual *writing* of the value to said file.

Comment: Okay, I am not using `kurczaki` anymore. I am using only `zmienna`. If I echo `zmienna`, then i am getting normal output, like `8`, etc. But when I am trying to output it to txt file, I am still getting: `ECHO is off.`

Comment: @Skrampy although this will not solve your problem, you should always use `ECHO(` instead of `ECHO` EXCEPT `echo off` or `echo on`

Comment: btw, why not `set/a"zmienna-=_rand"`?

Comment: like I said, I am new into batch. I bet, that I could write whole code better, but I am starting to use .bat :))